# Why WebPack is called a bundler? What is the use of bundling?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new to JS world and I am learning Angular.

I don't understand what is 'Bundling' in WebPack.

As per what i understand, Angular project will have a hundreds of JS files. If we were to serve all those files in one go to the browser, it may increase the loading time.

WebPack will bundle all those JS files in to one single bundle.js file. So that the load time will be less?

If so, how come it takes less time? We just combined all .js files to one big js file and should take same time to download?

I am confused!

Comment: This is too broad a question for SO, but maybe see https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ as a starting point.

Comment: Say you have to go to the garage and bring back 10 tools. Is it faster to do one trip and bring back a box with the 10 tools, or to do 10 trips and bring back one tool every time? Same for JS bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Bundling the files into one (or a few) download(s) means that all the resources needed will be available when the script starts executing. If the scripts are `require`d dynamically from the browser, once the first script starts running, it will have to wait for each resource that it requires to load before it can execute. Since those resources may, in turn, require other resources, there is a potentially long chain of requested resources that have to be received before any useful code gets executed. WebPack allows you to configure it to produce more than one bundle, and to provide you with script tags that can load the scripts in parallel, to allow the time to first interaction to be optimized.